# Doxygen is not generating call graphs for most methods/functions

Tags: c#, doxygen, call-graph

**this seems to be a bug. link to bugreport: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=731363**

I'm using Doxygen 1.8.7 and Graphviz 2.38. I configured Doxygen to scan a bigger project and generate the documentation as HTML page.

Now, I want/need the caller/called graphs in there and I set every flag that could have something to do with it to 'YES'. But the result is still the same: For 4 methods a called/caller graph is generated but not for the other methods.

I checked the logfile of Doxygen and found exactly 4 entries like this: `Generating caller graph for function [...]`

For every other class there is only the `Generating docs for compound [...]...`

Is there a way to get a more detailed log/reasons why doxygen refuses to generate caller graphs for functions?

My doxygen config:

```
# Doxyfile 1.8.7

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Project related configuration options
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DOXYFILE_ENCODING      = UTF-8
PROJECT_NAME           = testproject
PROJECT_NUMBER         = 
PROJECT_BRIEF          = 
PROJECT_LOGO           = 
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = "D:/path/to/outputdirectory"
CREATE_SUBDIRS         = NO
ALLOW_UNICODE_NAMES    = NO
OUTPUT_LANGUAGE        = English
BRIEF_MEMBER_DESC      = YES
REPEAT_BRIEF           = YES
ABBREVIATE_BRIEF       = "The $name class" \
                         "The $name widget" \
                         "The $name file" \
                         is \
                         provides \
                         specifies \
                         contains \
                         represents \
                         a \
                         an \
                         the
ALWAYS_DETAILED_SEC    = NO
INLINE_INHERITED_MEMB  = NO
FULL_PATH_NAMES        = YES
STRIP_FROM_PATH        = 
STRIP_FROM_INC_PATH    = 
SHORT_NAMES            = NO
JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF      = NO
QT_AUTOBRIEF           = NO
MULTILINE_CPP_IS_BRIEF = NO
INHERIT_DOCS           = YES
SEPARATE_MEMBER_PAGES  = NO
TAB_SIZE               = 4
ALIASES                = 
TCL_SUBST              = 
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C  = NO
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_JAVA   = YES
OPTIMIZE_FOR_FORTRAN   = NO
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_VHDL   = NO
EXTENSION_MAPPING      = 
MARKDOWN_SUPPORT       = YES
AUTOLINK_SUPPORT       = YES
BUILTIN_STL_SUPPORT    = NO
CPP_CLI_SUPPORT        = NO
SIP_SUPPORT            = NO
IDL_PROPERTY_SUPPORT   = YES
DISTRIBUTE_GROUP_DOC   = NO
SUBGROUPING            = YES
INLINE_GROUPED_CLASSES = NO
INLINE_SIMPLE_STRUCTS  = NO
TYPEDEF_HIDES_STRUCT   = NO
LOOKUP_CACHE_SIZE      = 0
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Build related configuration options
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = YES
EXTRACT_PACKAGE        = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_CLASSES  = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS  = NO
EXTRACT_ANON_NSPACES   = NO
HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS     = NO
HIDE_UNDOC_CLASSES     = NO
HIDE_FRIEND_COMPOUNDS  = NO
HIDE_IN_BODY_DOCS      = NO
INTERNAL_DOCS          = NO
CASE_SENSE_NAMES       = NO
HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES       = NO
SHOW_INCLUDE_FILES     = YES
SHOW_GROUPED_MEMB_INC  = NO
FORCE_LOCAL_INCLUDES   = NO
INLINE_INFO            = YES
SORT_MEMBER_DOCS       = YES
SORT_BRIEF_DOCS        = NO
SORT_MEMBERS_CTORS_1ST = NO
SORT_GROUP_NAMES       = NO
SORT_BY_SCOPE_NAME     = NO
STRICT_PROTO_MATCHING  = NO
GENERATE_TODOLIST      = YES
GENERATE_TESTLIST      = YES
GENERATE_BUGLIST       = YES
GENERATE_DEPRECATEDLIST= YES
ENABLED_SECTIONS       = 
MAX_INITIALIZER_LINES  = 30
SHOW_USED_FILES        = YES
SHOW_FILES             = YES
SHOW_NAMESPACES        = YES
FILE_VERSION_FILTER    = 
LAYOUT_FILE            = 
CITE_BIB_FILES         = 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to warning and progress messages
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
QUIET                  = NO
WARNINGS               = YES
WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED   = YES
WARN_IF_DOC_ERROR      = YES
WARN_NO_PARAMDOC       = NO
WARN_FORMAT            = "$file:$line: $text"
WARN_LOGFILE           = 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the input files
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
INPUT                  = C:/path/to/sourcecode
INPUT_ENCODING         = UTF-8
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.c \
                         *.cc \
                         *.cxx \
                         *.cpp \
                         *.c++ \
                         *.java \
                         *.ii \
                         *.ixx \
                         *.ipp \
                         *.i++ \
                         *.inl \
                         *.idl \
                         *.ddl \
                         *.odl \
                         *.h \
                         *.hh \
                         *.hxx \
                         *.hpp \
                         *.h++ \
                         *.cs \
                         *.d \
                         *.php \
                         *.php4 \
                         *.php5 \
                         *.phtml \
                         *.inc \
                         *.m \
                         *.markdown \
                         *.md \
                         *.mm \
                         *.dox \
                         *.py \
                         *.f90 \
                         *.f \
                         *.for \
                         *.tcl \
                         *.vhd \
                         *.vhdl \
                         *.ucf \
                         *.qsf \
                         *.as \
                         *.js
RECURSIVE              = YES
EXCLUDE                = obj\
EXCLUDE_SYMLINKS       = NO
EXCLUDE_PATTERNS       = 
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS        = 
EXAMPLE_PATH           = 
EXAMPLE_PATTERNS       = *
EXAMPLE_RECURSIVE      = YES
IMAGE_PATH             = 
INPUT_FILTER           = 
FILTER_PATTERNS        = 
FILTER_SOURCE_FILES    = YES
FILTER_SOURCE_PATTERNS = 
USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE = 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to source browsing
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SOURCE_BROWSER         = YES
INLINE_SOURCES         = NO
STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS    = YES
REFERENCED_BY_RELATION = YES
REFERENCES_RELATION    = YES
REFERENCES_LINK_SOURCE = YES
SOURCE_TOOLTIPS        = YES
USE_HTAGS              = NO
VERBATIM_HEADERS       = YES
CLANG_ASSISTED_PARSING = NO
CLANG_OPTIONS          = 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the alphabetical class index
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ALPHABETICAL_INDEX     = YES
COLS_IN_ALPHA_INDEX    = 5
IGNORE_PREFIX          = 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the HTML output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_HTML          = YES
HTML_OUTPUT            = html
HTML_FILE_EXTENSION    = .html
HTML_HEADER            = 
HTML_FOOTER            = 
HTML_STYLESHEET        = 
HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET  = 
HTML_EXTRA_FILES       = 
HTML_COLORSTYLE_HUE    = 220
HTML_COLORSTYLE_SAT    = 100
HTML_COLORSTYLE_GAMMA  = 80
HTML_TIMESTAMP         = YES
HTML_DYNAMIC_SECTIONS  = NO
HTML_INDEX_NUM_ENTRIES = 100
GENERATE_DOCSET        = NO
DOCSET_FEEDNAME        = "Doxygen generated docs"
DOCSET_BUNDLE_ID       = com.doxygen.project
DOCSET_PUBLISHER_ID    = com.doxygen.project.documentation
DOCSET_PUBLISHER_NAME  = Publisher
GENERATE_HTMLHELP      = NO
CHM_FILE               = 
HHC_LOCATION           = 
GENERATE_CHI           = NO
CHM_INDEX_ENCODING     = 
BINARY_TOC             = NO
TOC_EXPAND             = NO
GENERATE_QHP           = NO
QCH_FILE               = 
QHP_NAMESPACE          = org.doxygen.Project
QHP_VIRTUAL_FOLDER     = doc
QHP_CUST_FILTER_NAME   = 
QHP_CUST_FILTER_ATTRS  = 
QHP_SECT_FILTER_ATTRS  = 
QHG_LOCATION           = 
GENERATE_ECLIPSEHELP   = NO
ECLIPSE_DOC_ID         = org.doxygen.Project
DISABLE_INDEX          = NO
GENERATE_TREEVIEW      = YES
ENUM_VALUES_PER_LINE   = 4
TREEVIEW_WIDTH         = 250
EXT_LINKS_IN_WINDOW    = NO
FORMULA_FONTSIZE       = 10
FORMULA_TRANSPARENT    = YES
USE_MATHJAX            = NO
MATHJAX_FORMAT         = HTML-CSS
MATHJAX_RELPATH        = http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest
MATHJAX_EXTENSIONS     = 
MATHJAX_CODEFILE       = 
SEARCHENGINE           = YES
SERVER_BASED_SEARCH    = NO
EXTERNAL_SEARCH        = NO
SEARCHENGINE_URL       = 
SEARCHDATA_FILE        = searchdata.xml
EXTERNAL_SEARCH_ID     = 
EXTRA_SEARCH_MAPPINGS  = 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the LaTeX output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_LATEX         = NO
LATEX_OUTPUT           = latex
LATEX_CMD_NAME         = latex
MAKEINDEX_CMD_NAME     = makeindex
COMPACT_LATEX          = NO
PAPER_TYPE             = a4
EXTRA_PACKAGES         = 
LATEX_HEADER           = 
LATEX_FOOTER           = 
LATEX_EXTRA_FILES      = 
PDF_HYPERLINKS         = YES
USE_PDFLATEX           = YES
LATEX_BATCHMODE        = NO
LATEX_HIDE_INDICES     = NO
LATEX_SOURCE_CODE      = NO
LATEX_BIB_STYLE        = plain
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the RTF output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_RTF           = NO
RTF_OUTPUT             = rtf
COMPACT_RTF            = NO
RTF_HYPERLINKS         = NO
RTF_STYLESHEET_FILE    = 
RTF_EXTENSIONS_FILE    = 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the man page output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_MAN           = NO
MAN_OUTPUT             = man
MAN_EXTENSION          = .3
MAN_SUBDIR             = 
MAN_LINKS              = NO
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the XML output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_XML           = NO
XML_OUTPUT             = xml
XML_PROGRAMLISTING     = YES
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the DOCBOOK output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_DOCBOOK       = NO
DOCBOOK_OUTPUT         = docbook
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options for the AutoGen Definitions output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_AUTOGEN_DEF   = NO
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the Perl module output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_PERLMOD       = NO
PERLMOD_LATEX          = NO
PERLMOD_PRETTY         = YES
PERLMOD_MAKEVAR_PREFIX = 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the preprocessor
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION        = NO
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = NO
SEARCH_INCLUDES        = YES
INCLUDE_PATH           = 
INCLUDE_FILE_PATTERNS  = 
PREDEFINED             = 
EXPAND_AS_DEFINED      = 
SKIP_FUNCTION_MACROS   = YES
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to external references
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TAGFILES               = 
GENERATE_TAGFILE       = 
ALLEXTERNALS           = NO
EXTERNAL_GROUPS        = YES
EXTERNAL_PAGES         = YES
PERL_PATH              = /usr/bin/perl
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the dot tool
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CLASS_DIAGRAMS         = YES
MSCGEN_PATH            = 
DIA_PATH               = 
HIDE_UNDOC_RELATIONS   = NO
HAVE_DOT               = YES
DOT_NUM_THREADS        = 0
DOT_FONTNAME           = Helvetica
DOT_FONTSIZE           = 10
DOT_FONTPATH           = 
CLASS_GRAPH            = YES
COLLABORATION_GRAPH    = YES
GROUP_GRAPHS           = YES
UML_LOOK               = NO
UML_LIMIT_NUM_FIELDS   = 10
TEMPLATE_RELATIONS     = NO
INCLUDE_GRAPH          = YES
INCLUDED_BY_GRAPH      = YES
CALL_GRAPH             = YES
CALLER_GRAPH           = YES
GRAPHICAL_HIERARCHY    = YES
DIRECTORY_GRAPH        = YES
DOT_IMAGE_FORMAT       = svg
INTERACTIVE_SVG        = YES
DOT_PATH               = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin"
DOTFILE_DIRS           = 
MSCFILE_DIRS           = 
DIAFILE_DIRS           = 
DOT_GRAPH_MAX_NODES    = 50
MAX_DOT_GRAPH_DEPTH    = 0
DOT_TRANSPARENT        = NO
DOT_MULTI_TARGETS      = NO
GENERATE_LEGEND        = YES
DOT_CLEANUP            = YES
```

**edit**

It seems like the call graphs are only generated if the caller/called method is inside the same class. However there seems to be a different behavior for interfaces.

**edit2**

okay, I created a testproject which, on first glance, seems to confirm what I wrote in the first edit. Here is the testcode:

```
public class Class1
{
    public void SomePublicMethod()
    {
        Refresh();
    }

    public void SomeOtherPublicMethod()
    {
        SomePublicMethod();
    }

    private void SomePrivateMethod()
    {
        SomeOtherPublicMethod();
        Refresh();
    }

    private static void Refresh()
    {
    }
}

public class Class2
{
    private Class1 test2;
    public void ConstructingClass1()
    {
        Class1 test = new Class1();
        test.SomeOtherPublicMethod();
        test2 = new Class1();
    }

    public void CallingAllPublicsOfClass1()
    {
        test2.SomeOtherPublicMethod();
        test2.SomePublicMethod();

    }
}
```

Create a .NET 4 or 4.5 solution, create 2 class files and copy&paste the above code in there (should compile). Now let doxygen run over that. It'll create caller/called graphs for all methods in Class1, excluding everything from Class2. Meaning you won't see that `SomeOtherPublicMethod` is called from `Class2.ConstructingClass1`.

If you change to class2 there won't be any caller/called graphs at all.

**edit3**

you can also put both classes in the same file and it still won't generate graphs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It resolved in this commit.
https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/commit/7edbf2b2e705eccc0d99cce86149228473bc7f3e

So probably the next release will include this bug fix.

Comment: This should be upvoted more - I struggled several hours before finding this, caller graphs are now generated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Doxygen's code parser (which takes care of the code browser, the cross-references lists and the call graphs) is not perfect, so it probably lost track somewhere. Hard to tell where and why without a code example.

If you want accurate parsing you could try setting

```
 CLANG_ASSISTED_PARSING = YES
 CLANG_OPTIONS          = <compiler options>
```

then doxygen will use the clang compiler front-end to parse the code. You will probably get better warnings about what is missing and will need to adjust `CLANG_OPTIONS` such that these warnings go away in order to be sure you get accurate call graphs.

Comment: thanks for the response. I made an edit to my question, could you clarify if the observed behavior is 'normal'? Or if, in theory, it should generate 'global' caller/called graphs?

Comment: provided code sample. Also I'm not sure what CLANG has to do with C#...I activated it anyway but no errors/warnings were generated.

Comment: CLANG is for C/C++ only indeed. I didn't gather that you were using C# based on your original question. With the extra info I can now reproduce the problem. I agree this should have worked, so please file a bug report here https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=doxygen and cross-link to this page

Comment: will do :). `I didn't gather that you were using C#`, it's one of the tags ;)

Oh, also if you could add the fact that this is most likely a bug to your answer, I'd mark it as 'the' answer.

Answer (score 1):

### Getting Doxygen to generate call and caller graphs for *all* functions

For people still experiencing the call graphs not getting generated for some or many functions, such as I was experiencing today, you may need to increase the `DOT_GRAPH_MAX_NODES` value from `50` to `200` or more, depending on how many "nodes" a given function has (ie: how many functions it calls).

If the root nodes (ex: all of the functions) called within another function exceed this `DOT_GRAPH_MAX_NODES` value, then *no graph will be shown at all*. Here is the official wording in the default doxygen configuration file created by `doxygen -g Doxyfile` (emphasis added):

> The `DOT_GRAPH_MAX_NODES` tag can be used to set the maximum number of nodes that will be shown in the graph. If the number of nodes in a graph becomes larger than this value, doxygen will truncate the graph, which is visualized by representing a node as a red box. Note that doxygen **if the number of direct children of the root node in a graph is already larger than `DOT_GRAPH_MAX_NODES` then the graph will not be shown at all.**

You also need to be sure to have the necessary "extract" settings on, to enable extracting (generating) graphs from all of these types of things:

```bash
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = YES
EXTRACT_PRIV_VIRTUAL   = YES
EXTRACT_PACKAGE        = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_CLASSES  = YES  # is already YES by default
EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS  = YES  # only affects Objective-C code
EXTRACT_ANON_NSPACES   = YES
RESOLVE_UNNAMED_PARAMS = YES  # is already YES by default
```

And you need to enable `dot` and call and caller graphs:

```
HAVE_DOT               = YES
CALL_GRAPH             = YES
CALLER_GRAPH           = YES
```

Manually open your own Doxyfile doxygen configuration file for detailed descriptions of each one of those settings.

### References

1. For more details, see my personal notes and setup instructions here in my [eRCaGuy_dotfiles](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles) repo here: [Doxygen installation and setup](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/tree/master/Doxygen).

### See also

1. My answer: [Ask Ubuntu: How to install Doxygen on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1502796/327339)